# Authentication errors in react/redux application

Tags: authentication, reactjs, redux, bcrypt, react-redux

I am building authentication (using bcrypt, jwt) for an app -- react/redux/webpack -- and I am having an issue connecting my authentication functions to my login container (a login form that I want to run the functions in the below authentication file and post users to our db).

When I try to import the signin function (import { signin } from './Auth/controllers/authentication') from my authentication code (below) in to my login container, I get a nasty error. What am I doing wrong? How can I use the authentication functions within my login modal/screen?

```
ERROR in ./~/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js
Module parse failed: /Users/myname/Desktop/SaltyEndzone/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js?{"presets":["es2015","react"]}!/Users/myname/Desktop/groupname/node_modules/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js Line 293: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   rounds = r1 + r2;
|   real_salt = salt.substring(off + 3, off + 25);
|   password = password + (minor >= 'a' ? "\000" : "");
| 
|   var buf = new Buffer(password);
 @ ./public/Login/Auth/models/user.js 6:13-37
```

So that's (one of the errors) and now here's the code (authentication below, and the login modal as well):

```
//authentication.js

const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const config = require('../config');

const User = require('../models/user');


function tokenForUser(user) {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();

  return jwt.encode({ sub: user.id, iat: timestamp }, config.secret);
}


exports.signin = function(req, res, next) {

  res.send( {token: tokenForUser(req.user)} );
}


exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
  const email =  req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;


  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(422).send({error: 'You must provide email and password'});
  }

          User.findOne( {email: email }, function(err, existingUser) {
    if(err) { 
      return next(err); 
    }


    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(422).send({error: 'Email is in use'})
    }


    const user = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password
    });

    user.save(function(err){
      if(err) {
        return next(err);
      }

  res.json({token: tokenForUser(user)});
    });    

  });
}
```

And here is the login code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { signin } from './Auth/controllers/authentication';


export default class Login extends Component {

  render() {

    const { openLogin, closeLogin, login } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login-corner">
         <span className="login" onClick={openLogin}>LOGIN</span> 
        </div>
          <Modal className="modal-dialog" bsSize="small" show={login.login} closeTimeoutMS={150}>
            <Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Title className="login-title">Login</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Body>
            <div className="login-input">
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="user-input">
                  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                  <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
                <div className="password-input">
                  <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                  <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="login-button">
              <Button className="btn btn-info" onClick={closeLogin}>Welcome Back!</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="register-button">
              <a className="register-link" ui-sref="register" onClick={closeLogin}>Not a member? Sign up!</a> 
            </div>
          </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The repo for bcrypt-nodejs seems to [no longer be maintained](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs/issues/59). The suggested replacement is [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).